# AWS SNS get topic by name

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I started to work with AWS SNS to send push notifications to my app. Today, to get a topic that I want to send push notifications to, I need to load all topics – using SNS client function listTopics() - and check each topic to see if the ARN has the name of the topic that I'm looking for.

I think that it's a very inefficient way to get a topic ARN, and I'd like to know if there is a most efficient way to get this information, like a function getTopicByName or something else.

If not, I'd like to know if ARN is immutable, and if can I store the topic ARN on my database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know of any way to look up an SNS topic by name.

The ARN is immutable. It will not change for the life of the SNS topic. In particular, according to [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-sns) an ARN for an SNS topic is in the following format:

`arn:aws:sns:region:account-id:topicname`

So the only way for the SNS topic's ARN to change would be to change the name (in which case your lookup by name would also break), or delete the topic and recreate it in a new region or in an entirely different account, in which case it would not really the same topic anymore.

Comment: Thanks man, on last doubt, this rule of arn works for any arn (topic, endpoint, application, etc)?

Comment: Yes they shouldn't change

Answer (score 16):

If you know the topic already exists or you don't care if it gets created, then a much more direct approach is simply to call [`CreateTopic`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_CreateTopic.html). Given a name, `CreateTopic` will return the existing topic, including the ARN.

Comment: it seems like this is not working when the topic was created using a cloudformation template. I am getting an unauthorized error despite granting access to all sns resources

Answer (score 8):

If the topic is already available,then you can use the "createTopic" method as follows.With this if the requester already owns a topic with the specified name, that topic's ARN is returned without creating a new topic. In AWS Java SDK, the code will looks like this.

```
    AWSCredentialsProvider provider = new ProfileCredentialsProvider();
    AmazonSNS sns = AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(provider).build();
    CreateTopicResult createRes = sns.createTopic("HelloTopic");
```

Then by using CreateTopicResult you can obtain the Topic ARN and publish the message

```
sns.publish(new PublishRequest(createRes.getTopicArn(), "Hello World"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Although the given answers here to use the `SnsClient.createTopic()` method will work, they also require that the role running this code has the `sns:CreateTopic` policy which may not be ideal.